# Sending huge amount of emails using Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-ses

I'm going to use Amazon SES for sending emails in the website I'm building currently. According to the sample java code they have provided in their API documentation I developed the functionality and I was able to send the emails. But when it comes to handle huge number of emails in a very short time of period what is the best mechanism to follow up? Do they provide any queue mechanism for emails? I couldn't find this from their API documentation and their technical service is available only for users who has purchased the account.

Can anyone has come across a solution for this problem?

Comment: *"what is the best mechanism to follow up?"* What does this question mean? *"Do they provide any queue mechanism for emails?"* A queue mechanism for what purpose?  Once you have submitted an email to SES, it has internal queues, but those aren't really relevant, so again, I have to ask... what does this question mean?  "Queue mechanism," for what reason or propose?  Please clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I use a custom SQS solution for a batch mailing process like this.

Sending more than a few emails from a web server isn't ideal, so I usually only have the website submit the request for the emails to a back-end process in a single call, then I create an SQS message for each recipient and (in my case) use a windows service that requests messages from SQS and sends the emails at the pace I want them to go out. If errors are encountered the message stays in the queue, and get retried automatically.

With an architecture like this, depending on your volumes you can spin up new instances automatically if the SQS queue size gets too large for a single instance to process in a timely manner.